# Update row with values from select on condition, else insert new row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, upsert

I'm need to run a calculation for month every day.  If the month period, exists already, I need to update it, else I need to create a new row for the new month.

Currently, I've written

```
declare @period varchar(4) = '0218'
DECLARE @Timestamp date = GetDate()

IF EXISTS(select * from #output where period=@period)
  /* UPDATE #output SET  --- same calculation as below ---*/
ELSE
   SELECT
    @period AS period,
    SUM(timecard.tworkdol) AS dol_local,
    SUM(timecard.tworkdol/currates.cdrate) AS dol_USD,
    SUM(timecard.tworkhrs) AS hrs,
    @Timestamp AS timestamp
FROM dbo.timecard AS timecard
    INNER JOIN dbo.timekeep ON timecard.ttk = timekeep.tkinit
    INNER JOIN dbo.matter with (nolock) on timecard.tmatter = matter.mmatter
    LEFT JOIN dbo.currates with (nolock) on matter.mcurrency = currates.curcode 
        AND currates.trtype = 'A' 
        AND timecard.tworkdt BETWEEN currates.cddate1 
        AND currates.cddate2
WHERE   timekeep.tkloc IN('06','07') AND
    timecard.twoper = @period

SELECT * FROM #output;
```

How can simply update my row with the new data from my select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what RDBMS are you using, but in SQL Server something like this would update the `#output` table with the results of the `SELECT` that you placed in the `ELSE` part:

```
UPDATE o
    SET o.dol_local = SUM(timecard.tworkdol),
    SET o.dol_USD = SUM(timecard.tworkdol/currates.cdrate),
    SET o.hrs = SUM(timecard.tworkhrs),
    set o.timestamp = @Timestamp
FROM #output o
INNER JOIN dbo.timecard AS timecard ON o.period = timecard.twoper
INNER JOIN dbo.timekeep ON timecard.ttk = timekeep.tkinit
INNER JOIN dbo.matter with (nolock) on timecard.tmatter = matter.mmatter
LEFT JOIN dbo.currates with (nolock) on matter.mcurrency = currates.curcode 
        AND currates.trtype = 'A' 
        AND timecard.tworkdt BETWEEN currates.cddate1 
        AND currates.cddate2
WHERE   timekeep.tkloc IN('06','07') AND
    timecard.twoper = @period
```

Also, I think you want to do an `INSERT` in the `ELSE` part, but you are doing just a `SELECT`, so I guess you should fix that too

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this will vary by SQL dialect, but the two main approaches are:
1. Upsert (if your DBMS supports it), for example using a MERGE statement in SQL Server.
2. Base your SQL on an IF:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (criteria for dupes)
 INSERT INTO (logic to insert)
ELSE
 UPDATE (logic to update)
```